# NSTableCellView subclass for disclosure button like in Console.app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nstablecellview

In my NSTableView, I'd like to have cells like Console.app: with a disclosure triangle button on left to expand the line if text is truncated.

Someone advised me to subclass NSTableCellView, but after few tries, I'm lost between programming and IB.

Can someone show me the pseudo code for the display of this button ? (Then the delegate and actions to resize the line will be another matter ...)

Comment: Kindly explain what you exactly want to know? How to subclass or how to implement delegate and actions?

Comment: How to subclass as a priority

Comment: interface MyNSTableCellView : NSTableCellView {
-(returnType)methodName;
end

Comment: Actually I'd like to know how must be coded my subclass to incorporate the display button on left of MyNSTableCellView, and keep some text on the right part ?